# Apache Spark Delay Between Jobs

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, delay

my as you can see, my small application has 4 jobs which run for a total duration of 20.2 seconds, however there is a big delay between job 1 and 2 causing the total time to be over a minute. Job number 1 **runJob at SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter.scala:88** is performing a bulkupload of HFiles into a HBase table. Here is the code I used to load to load the files

```
val outputDir = new Path(HBaseUtils.getHFilesStorageLocation(resolvedTableName))
val job = Job.getInstance(hBaseConf)
job.getConfiguration.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, resolvedTableName)
job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[HFileOutputFormat2])
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable])
job.setMapOutputValueClass(classOf[KeyValue])
val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(job.getConfiguration)
val hBaseAdmin = connection.getAdmin
val table = TableName.valueOf(Bytes.toBytes(resolvedTableName))
val tab = connection.getTable(table).asInstanceOf[HTable]
val bulkLoader = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(job.getConfiguration)
preBulkUploadCallback.map(callback => callback())
bulkLoader.doBulkLoad(outputDir, hBaseAdmin, tab, tab.getRegionLocator)
```

If anyone has any ideas, I would be very greatful

[image: Spark History UI - Jobs Timeline]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see there are 26 tasks in job 1 which is based on the number of hfiles created. Even though the job 2 shows completed in 2s, it takes some time to copy these files to target location and that's why you are getting a delay between job 2 and 3. This can be avoided by reducing the number of tasks in job 1.

Answer (score 1):

Decrease the number of Regions for the output table in Hbase, which will result in reducing the number of task for your second job.

TableOutputFormat determines the split based on the number of regions for a given table in Hbase

Answer (score 1):

> Job number 1 runJob at SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter.scala:88 is performing a bulkupload

This is not quite true. This job merely creates HFiles **outside** of HBase. The gap you see between this job and the next one could be explained by the **actual bulk loading** at `bulkLoader.doBulkLoad`. This operation involves only metadata trasfer and usually performs faster (from my experience), so you should check the driver logs to see where it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input guys, I lowered the number of HFiles created in task 0. This has decreased the lag by about 20%. I used

```
HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(job, tab, tab.getRegionLocator)
```

which automatically calculates the number of reduce tasks to match the current number of regions for the table. I will say that we are are using HBase backed by S3 in AWS EMR instead of the classical HDFS. I'm am going to investigate now whether this could be contributing to the lag.